# How to swallow touches on CCMenu while sliding?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm creating a sliding menu for my game something like angry birds level selection but I'm having problem with buttons. If I accidentally touch any of the buttons while swiping the level starts to load.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the level loads when the button receives ccTouchMoved. Try to make the level load when the button receives ccTouchEnded.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what the equivalent would in coco be but maybe make the buttons touch intent where as if they are touched for a length of time then start level otherwise ignore, you should be able to swipe across them all without being on a single button long enough to start the level.